# How to manage to 2 languages for posts in Tumblr, on the blog and on the dashboard?

Tags: javascript, html, localization, translation, tumblr

I have  a blog on Tumblr where I post small texts. I want to have these texts in Spanish and English, and that is no difficult from the "Blog" side. I can make a JavaScript selector and hide the Spanish paragraph  or the English paragraph depending on the selection of the user.

But what about the dashboard? The people that follows me will see my posts on their dashboard, and there they will see both paragraphs with no possibility of managing this.

Any ideas? you know how people solve this?

Comment: AFAIK, this isn't possible. The sensible thing to do would be to set up a blog for each language.